# Maven redistribute existing war (no command line)

Tags: java, maven, war, distribute

I have a complex maven project whose build artifacts are published automatically to a Nexus.

In the source code, I have `Test.war`: a *WAR provided as-is* by a third-party. Such archive is built manually by them, not available in Nexus, and does not have GAV identifier.

During my complex build, I need to "*re-distribut*e" (or "rebuild"?) this *provided war* using new, defined GAV coordinates (e.g. `test-group:Test-Web:1.0.0`).

*Note*: I cannot execute a command like `mvn deploy:deploy-file` because we don't have direct access to the Nexus. The only way to deploy artifacts to Nexus, is to generate the artifacts during a build, and then such artifacts are automatically published.

Is there anyone who can provide me a suggestion or an example on how I can *re-deploy* such war during the build?

Comment: Would it be ok to add the `deploy-file` goal to your POM, so that the normal build process (I assume something like `mvn clean deploy`) will run the goal?

Comment: Can you please more elaborate in detail what you need to do? Cause I don't understand why you can't refer the `Test.war`?

Comment: `Test.war` is a (fake) name for a third party WAR that I need to redeploy during the build of a given maven project. I am now editing the question so that it is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "re-distribute" you mean that your build needs to deploy the WAR to nexus under the different GAV.

In this case you might consider using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` plugin.

This goal of the deploy plugin installs the file into remote repository and allows specifing the GAV of the artifact file that you want to deploy.

When WAR is created it doesn't contain any GAV, the GAV is used solely to identify the artifact in the maven repo (remote or local).

You can find an example [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I already took a look at the solution and it is non-viable. As I wrote in the question, I need to have a project that deploys the artifact under a new GAV. Indeed, the results of my build are automatically deployed to Nexus, and I cannot execute a command like `mvn deploy:deploy-file ..` (I am updating the question to make this clearer - thanks anyway for the high quality answer)

Comment: Note sure I'm following: in general you can create deploy:deploy file as a plugin in your pom.xml as well and assign it to "deploy" phase that in general is supposed to deploy your own artifact. Having said that I don't know what kind of artifact do you build in your pom (the question was focused on the Test.war). Maybe you can describe more your building process, for instance what exactly Test.war is used for and why it should be distributed under different GAVs, then our colleagues or me could provide a better answer...

Comment: Sure, here is what happens: We have a maven build, that using a specific profile, publishes resulting artifacts to a customer's nexus. Now, we need to deploy `Test.war` (a stripped-down version of an existing war)  that was "changed manually" by another team. Such new war, is in a `lib` folder in our codebase, and needs to be published in the same nexus. Therefore, my idea is to add another project with packaging: war, and then somehow build  the `Test.war` and auto-publish it to Nexus. (as said, the new versioned `Test.war` should be an artifact published by our build.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you want to deploy:deploy-file plugin's goal in your pom.xml and attach it to the deploy phase of the default lifecycle? It doesn't have to be run "explicitly", instead this goal can be configured to be run during the `mvn deploy` command that I suppose you're running to publish your own artifacts. This goal could accept parameters with GAV you want to deploy as well as a file of your choice (Test.war from the lib folder)? Am I missing something?

Comment: Now that I am reading again your answer, I realized I could execute the deploy:deploy-file plugin as a plugin of a normal maven project, if tied to the correct phase. I was missing the fact that is possible to run the plugin inside a normal pom.xml because the linked example shows only the command-line version: `mvn deploy:deploy-file`.